# Use git sparse checkout to workaround file name with colon

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

When I clone a repository on Windows, it complains about a file name with colon, so checkout fails. I want to use sparse checkout to exclude the whole directory, but it doesn't work. Is sparse checkout the correct way to help here?

My steps:

```
git init <project_name>
cd <project_name>
git remote add origin http://<url>.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "folder1" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout 
echo "folder2" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout // exclude folder3 as it causes trouble.
git pull origin master
```

However it still downloads everything and checkout to master fails because of that file with a colon in its name. Am I doing everying correctly and is sparse checkout the correct way to help me?

Comment: `core.sparsecheckout` is not a valid configuration attribute, this is `core.sparseCheckout`, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/10155936)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Comment: Seems I find the root cause, in Windows should not include double quotes when use echo command, removing the double quotes and use exclamation make whole things work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause: I should not include double quotes when calling `echo`, and using the exclamation mark can make the whole thing easier if only few folders need to be excluded.

Here is my script:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto blank

git init %1
cd %1
git remote add origin http://<url>.git
git config core.sparseCheckout true
(
  echo /*
  echo !/<dir needs to be excluded>
) > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
echo repo created in %1.
goto :EOF

:blank
echo Please specify a folder name.
```